# Are push notifications normally slow?

Tags: push-notifications, oxygenos

I have a persistent problem with notifications to all apps on my OnePlus6+ where they typically are delayed 30-60s, often I will get several notifications showing at once or when I unlock my phone suddenly I get notifications.

I can test with gmail, Slack, Messenger, WhatsApp and any other app where I have a version open on my PC at the same time

I've only ever owned Android smartphones, and only from OnePlus so I do not know if this is just how Android works or is a 'feature' of OxygenOS/OnePlus hardware. But it's happened across multiple versions of Android and hardware for several years.

It suggest PUSH notifications are not really being PUSHed but polled, like the phone is only checking periodically.

I see it whether on WiFi or cellular networks and it's quite irritating. Can anyone give me any information or advice about it?

Comment: Check from battery settings if these apps are battery optimised , if they are , remove from battery optimiztion. This seems to be a likely reason. [This would help you understand how push notifications work](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/how-do-push-notifications-work?rq=1)

Comment: You may also refer to [Don't kill my app](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) for some tips per device brand.

Comment: Early tests show I can turn off optimisation and _fingers crossed_ it is much better. I have one app I really need notifications to be delivered prompty.#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That push messages are not delivered in real-time is because of the battery optimization Android applies (this optimization may additionally also be applied by the Google servers providing the push messages).

The main idea behind the function to concentrate/group multiple notifications is that if you have multiple apps running waiting for incoming push messages it may end up that your device has to wake-up every few seconds and check for incoming push messages. A device that wakes up that often has a negative effect on on the battery so Google decided to group the messages and only check in every few minutes especially when the phone is not used for a certain time.

If I remember correctly this feature was introduced first in Android 7 and more and more extended with every new Android version.